# Integrating strike-through the list on its click or on selecting checkbox in to-do-list app?

Tags: vuejs2

I am creating a demo of todolist app and I want to strike-through the list on click of list or selecting particular checkbox. Here is my code:

```
 <div v-for="(item, index) in toDoList" :key="index">
   <v-checkbox v-model="item.status"></v-checkbox>
   <textfield>{{item.title}}</textfield>
 </div>
```

where status is having a boolean value.

Comment: Can you show us an MCVE?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `<textfield>` to be responding to click events, a small change to your markup is required:

```
<v-checkbox
  :label="item.title"
  v-model="item.status"
></v-checkbox>
```

And then you can add this additional style to your stylesheet to target the `<label>` element of a checked checkbox:

```
.input-group--active label {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    toDoList: [
      { title: 'Lorem', status: null },
      { title: 'ipsum', status: null },
      { title: 'dolor', status: null },
      { title: 'sit', status: null },
      { title: 'amet', status: null }
    ]
  }
});
```

```css
.input-group--active label {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>

<!-- Vuetify dependencies -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.0.14/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.0.14/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <div
    v-for="(item, index) in toDoList"
    :key="index">
    <v-checkbox
      :label="item.title"
      v-model="item.status"
    ></v-checkbox>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

An alternative solution is simply adding a custom class to your checked elements using `:class` binding, e.g.:

```
<div
    v-for="(item, index) in toDoList"
   :key="index"
   :bind="{ 'is-selected': item.status' }">
```

And for your CSS:

```
.is-selected label {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Note that since `text-decoration` is *not* inheritable, using `.is-selected { text-decoration: line-through; }` will not work. You will have to select for the descendant `<label>` element.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    toDoList: [
      { title: 'Lorem', status: null },
      { title: 'ipsum', status: null },
      { title: 'dolor', status: null },
      { title: 'sit', status: null },
      { title: 'amet', status: null }
    ]
  }
});
```

```css
.is-selected label {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>

<!-- Vuetify dependencies -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.0.14/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.0.14/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <div
    v-for="(item, index) in toDoList"
    :key="index"
    :class="{ 'is-selected': item.status }">
    <v-checkbox
      :label="item.title"
      v-model="item.status"
    ></v-checkbox>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thankx for the reply @terry, I have bind style on textfield, it works in case of selecting checkbox but I also want to integrate this functionality when user click on item. In that case how it should work?

Comment: @SukhpalSingh If that's the case, you shouldn't be using `<textlabel>` Instead, you want to bind the `item.title` to the `:label` property of `<v-checkbox>` instead: see updated answer. Also, check out Vuetify's example: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selection-controls#example-checkboxes-boolean